# Check if some variables in an array are equal and then assign those to another array

Tags: java, arrays

I have this one-dimensional array, that holds 4 values.

For example:

```
    moves[] = { 2, 2, 3, 3 };
```

I want to be able to check each value in the array that is equal and the smallest. So at the end I want my new array to be like this:

```
    moves1[] = {2, 2};
```

How can I achieve this in Java?

Comment: Is the input sorted?

Comment: "I want to be able to check each value in the array that is equal " <- equal to what? That sentence makes no sense. Equality is a relationship between two things, not the property of a single thing.

Comment: The input would not be sorted.

Comment: Equal to another value in the array as I showed, in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution does not assume that the array is sorted and has a runtime complexity of `O(n)`. Furthermore it has a very low memory footprint, since it does not create a copy of the array to sort it.

```
 public static int[] smallestAndEqual(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        return new int[0]; // can be cached if needed
    }

    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i : arr) {
        if (i < smallest) {
            smallest = i;
            count = 1;
        } else if (i == smallest) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    int[] ints = new int[count];
    Arrays.fill(ints, smallest);
    return ints;
}
```

An example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] ints = {2, 2, 3, 3};
    int[] result = smallestAndEqual(ints);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

Which outputs the following line when executed:

```
[2, 2]
```

Comment: If you assume that the input type must be generic: OP did explicity list a given input of `{2,2,3,3}`, which can only be an `int[]`. However, if the OP requires a generic solution, i recommend the question to be edited and i will adjust my answer accordingly or remove it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array, each time you encounter a new lower value, reset the result list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int moves[] = { 2, 2, 3, 3 };
    int lowest=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    List<Integer> low=new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(int i=0;i<moves.length;i++) {
        if(moves[i]<lowest)
        {
            low=new ArrayList<>();
            lowest=moves[i];
        } 
        if (moves[i]==lowest)
            low.add(moves[i]);
    }
    Integer[] result=low.toArray(new Integer[low.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But wouldn't result in the end only have 2? Instead of the 2, two's.

Comment: No, the result is {2,2} thanks to the second if: every figure which is equal to the lowest is also added to the result.